# Facebook connect, validate a site. &amp; and &

Tags: javascript, facebook, validation

I got the following problem.

I want to fully validate our site and we're using Facebook Connect to place like-boxes on your page.

The following javascript-src validates correctly

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=xxxxx&amp;xfbml=1"
```

But using `&amp;` makes the likebox vanish.

If I change it to:

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=xxxxx&xfbml=1"
```

The box appears, but the validator throws a error.

I've tried this workaround:

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=xxxxx&amp;xfbml=1".replace(/&/g, "&amp;");
```

But the validator throws this error:
*Line 34, Column 93: character "&" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data.* The box is also gone.

Is there any way to get around this problem? It is not 100% necessary, but I'd like to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [HTML Compatibility Guidelines for Embedded Style Sheets and Scripts](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_4).

Move the JS to an external file, or wrap the content of `<script>` elements in CDATA markers.

(Or switch to using HTML since true XHTML has limited support and is being treated as a distinctly second class citizen with current W3C spec design)